# VSIX registration and unregistration issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, vsix

I'm having some problems when registering and unregistering an extension in Visual Studio 2012 / 2013. The issue is the following:

**1.- Register an extension:**

```
vsixinstaller.exe myvsixpackage.vsix
```

A directory is created in my local folder, under C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions.

**2.- Unregister the extension:**

```
vsixinstaller.exe /u:myvsixID
```

This unregisters the extension, but **it does not remove the extension assemblies**; When I restart Visual Studio and plugins are loaded, the files are removed. It seems that the extensions **is marked to be removed later.**

**3.- Register the extension again.**

```
vsixinstaller.exe myvsixpackage.vsix
```

I get the error: *"This extension is already installed to all available products".*

But if I open VS2013 the extension is not there. Eventually I cannot even unregister it (VSIX installer says that the extension was already uninstalled) and I have to remove the  directory manually so that I can register my extension again.

Is there any workaround for this? Is it a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Visual Studio needs to be **started** in order to refresh all the Extensions registered and unregistered.

The best solution to register / unregister **silently** is running:

```
devenv /setup /nosetupvstemplates
```

After the plugin has been unregistered.

This executes the IDE but not showing it to the user. Perfect for including a Visual Studio Extension in a installer along with your main product, if publishing it in the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) is not a good approach.